# Http Request with Google API client library

Tags: java, httprequest, http-status-codes

I'm using Java in order to get some JSON files from an API (Authorisation required), but I haven't found how the set up the request probably.

I'm using the Google API Client Libary (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/)

This is my code:

```
 HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest;
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    request.execute();
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException
```

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong? I've not found any hint in the documentation.

PS: I wouldn't mind switching to another libary. I do need the HTML status code to catch some errors (which I haven't implemented yet).

Edit: thanks to daherens, my code does now look like this

`HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        try {
            request.execute();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Sadly there's still a "( or [ required" Error where 'response' is defined.

Edit2: It says that I need a HTTP Transport objekt. But even when creating it, it just says

```
'HttpRequest(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport, java.lang.String)' is not public in 'com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

I don't know either what a HTTP Transport object is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java functions and methods declare which exceptions they might raise and you **must** deal with that. Either by telling in your method that you'll also throws it, or by catching it yourself with try {} catch. Read more about this [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions)

Comment: @daherens: Thank you, that fixed one problem. Now my code looks like this:

Comment: `HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        try {
            request.execute();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
`
Sadly there's still a "( or [ required" Error where 'response' is defined.

Comment: may you add this formatted to your question - nearly unreadable :)

Comment: I've fixed the URL problem (it was actually a dumb mistake, but settig up the request still doesn't work (see code in Question)